# Javascript checking date

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to use JavaScript to validate that the date selected is not earlier than today, but when I select today's date it's showing the alert box.

JavaScript:

```
function checkDueDate(sender, args) {
    var td = new Date(); 
    td.setMinutes(59);
    td.setSeconds(59);
    td.setHours(23);
    //to move back one day
    td.setDate(td.getDate() - 1);

    if (sender._selectedDate < td) {
        alert("You can't select day from the past! " + td + "");
        sender._selectedDate = new Date();
        // set the date back to the current date
        sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
    }
```

ASP.NET:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDueDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="txtDueDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="txtDueDate" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDueDate">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

[image]

Comment: Tell us the problem, Seems you are getting what you want

Comment: I am using Ajax extender for date picker

Comment: The problem is today date 11/7/2012 and in the box i set 1 day before today to not show this box for todays date b/c I will allow for due date to be today.

Comment: do our answers solved out your problem if es, then don't forgot to accept..

Comment: What exactly does this line of code do? `sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you're complicating things too much. I would just subtract a day in miliseconds and it should work:

```
function isPast( date ) {
  return date.getTime() < (new Date().getTime() - 864e5); 
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/igeyov/1/edit

Comment: i am using date picker from ajax to select due date range

Comment: So... you can just pass the date from the datepicker to `isPast` as a `Date` object.

Comment: @Talha: It means _864 times 10 to the power 5_ which is the same as `86400000` which is one day in miliseconds. More info here http://www.mathsisfun.com/index-notation-powers.html. `e` is just a shortcut to _10 to power x_, `x` being the number after it.

Answer (score 0):

the logic you have here seems to do exactly what you want - you have set the td variable which you evaluate against to the last possible second of todays date and you are checking if the selected date is before or equal to that. Todays date IS "before or equal to" 23:59:59 today...

Also, you have tagged this with c# , although it is all javascript and ASP.net as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do select only future dates then you can try this code also....this is working with ajax calendar:

```
 function checkDate(sender, args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {
            alert("You can select only future day!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            // set the date back to the current date
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" Width="180px" MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxctrl:calendarextender onclientdateselectionchanged="checkDate" id="cale_txtDOB"
                                runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtDOB" format="MM/dd/yyyy" cssclass="cal_Theme1">
                            </ajaxctrl:calendarextender>
```

This code works only if you select past dates it will show a pop up " that you can not select past dates"  whatever be it. 
UPDATED CODE:
Here is code work if you dont want to include today's date also, you just want future dates only:

```
function checkDate(sender, args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate <= new Date()) {
            alert("You can select only future day!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            // set the date back to the current date
            //sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
        }
    }
```

hope this will help you..